# Creating Gantt charts with ggplot2: can the scale_x_date function display dates as quarters (eg Q4 2020)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gantt-chart

I'm preparing Gantt charts using ggplot2. I've found a mostly serviceable approach, but I'd like to further improve my output.

The following sample code creates a dataframe (set up like this because it's relatively easy to edit on the fly):

```
df <- as.data.frame(rbind(
    c("Category_1", "task_1", '2020-10-01', '2020-12-31'),
    c("Category_1", "task_2", '2021-01-01', '2021-04-01'),
    c("Category_2", "task_3", '2021-06-15', '2021-10-01'))) %>%
  select("Category" = 1, "task" = 2, "start" = 3, "end" = 4) %>%
  mutate(Category = (factor(Category, levels = (unique(Category)))),
         task = fct_rev(factor(task, levels = (task))),
         start = as.Date(start), 
         end = as.Date(end)) %>%
  mutate(lab_pos = start) %>%
  pivot_longer(3:4, names_to = "variable", values_to = "value")
```

Then this code creates the Gantt chart (simplified for sharing):

```
ggplot(df, aes(value, task, color = Category)) + 
  geom_line(size = 14, show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = " %y %b", 
               limits = c(as.Date('2020-06-30'), as.Date('2021-12-31')), 
               date_breaks = '3 months', date_minor_breaks = "1 month", 
               position = "top") +
  labs(x = NULLy = NULL) +
  facet_grid(Category ~ ., space = "free_y", scales = "free_y", switch = "both")
```

So the question is **how can I display the x-axis units generated by scale_x_date in quarters instead of dates?** For example, instead of 21 Jan, I'd prefer Q1 21. Is there a better approach vs scale_x_date?

A secondary question is: if I can get the quarter labels, can I move that label to the middle of the quarter, so that the major gridlines border the quarter and the label sits in between them, identifying the whole region as the quarter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `labels` parameter instead of `date_labels` and pass a custom function to extract the quarter information from the date.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(value, task, color = Category)) + 
  geom_line(size = 14, show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_x_date(labels =  function(x) paste(quarters(x), format(x, '%Y')),
               limits = c(as.Date('2020-06-30'), as.Date('2021-12-31')), 
               date_breaks = '3 months', date_minor_breaks = "1 month", 
               position = "top") +
  labs(x = NULL,y = NULL) +
  facet_grid(Category ~ ., space = "free_y", scales = "free_y", switch = "both")
```

[image]